# An irreducaible singular cubic hypersurface in $P^n$ is rational.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can I show an irreducaible singular cubic hypersurface in $P^n$ is rational.

Such question always seems very bizarre for me. Totally no idea. So can any one give me some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the first argument that came to mind. You should probably check the details.

Consider the family of lines passing through the singular point. You can think of this family as a $\mathbb P^{n-1}$. By Bezout's theorem, each line in this family intersects the cubic surface at precisely one other point on the surface. This gives a map $\mathbb P^{n-1}\rightarrow H$, the cubic hypersurface, which is birational.

Comment: It seems that I am not familiar with material here. So why the multiplicity at singular point is exactly 2 but not 3? And why we can think of the family as $P^{n-1}$? Thanks.

Comment: First question: if the multiplicity were 3, then no line through the given point would intersect the cubic hypersurface elsewhere. But this is absurd. (Pick any point on the hypersurface and consider the line joining that point and the singular point...)

Comment: Second question: Can you write down the general form of a linear passing through a given point? It will be easier if you suppose, without loss of generality, that the point is $[1:0:\dots:0]$.

Comment: So you mean the line is not must in the hypersurface?

Comment: If we are in $P^n$, why the family is not $p^n$?

Comment: I think you can show the hypersurface contains only finitely many lines, so the line lying in the hypersurface won't be an issue for the birational map. But yes, this is another detail to check.

Comment: What do you mean, why is the family not $\mathbb P^n$? Have you tried finding the general form of a line passing through the point I gave?

Comment: You write $P^{n-1}$ previously. I am totally confused. So do you mean the line is in the hypersurface? Or just line passing through the singular point in $P^n$. And what is special here for the singular point?

Comment: Yes, I think it should be $\mathbb P^{n-1}$. The line should pass through the singular point, but it might happen that such a line lies entirely in the hypersurface, so you can't set up the correspondence I indicated for such a line. I think this should only happen for a lower-dimensional set of lines, so it wouldn't be an issue when constructing the birational map.

Comment: @Vincent The singular point is special because any line passing through it must have intersection multiplicity at least $2$, I believe. If you pass a line through a smooth point, in general it will intersect the cubic hypersurface at two other points, so you don't get a map as I indicated in the answer.